# libpd for iOS Mach-O linker errors

Tags: ios, xcode, puredata, libpd

I'm using libpd in a universal iOS app, working with iOS 7 and Xcode 5.0.2.  libpd works as expected (can load and interact with Pd patches), but I'm having trouble using external objects.

Here's the error message I'm seeing:

```
Ld DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BrightHearts.app/BrightHearts normal armv7s
cd /Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
-F/Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/BrightHearts.build/Debug-iphoneos/BrightHearts.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/BrightHearts.LinkFileList 
-dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework GLKit -framework OpenGLES -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreText /Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libpd-ios.a 
-framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker 
/Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/BrightHearts.build/Debug-iphoneos/BrightHearts.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/BrightHearts_dependency_info.dat -o 
/Users/jman/Developer/Sensorium/brighthearts-beta/BrightHearts/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BrightHearts.app/BrightHearts

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_allsickles_setup", referenced from:
  -[SENViewController setupPD] in SENViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've seen the suggestion to set the 'Build Active Architecture' flag to YES for the libpd subproject - this doesn't make any difference, I still get the same error.

Is there a solution (obvious or otherwise) for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like you aren't actually compiling `allsickles.c` from the Cyclone external. That file has the method `void allsickles_setup(void)` which I guess you're trying to call to set up libpd.

If `allsickles.c` is in your project, maybe it's not actually getting compiled, so you might have to add it to "Compile Sources" under Build Phases.

Comment: I realised that the pd-for-ios (https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-ios) repository has an old libpd submodule, from December 2012. I replaced it with libpd from the main repo (https://github.com/libpd/libpd) and almost all of my compiler errors disappeared.